# Is there any ScalaConsole around?

Tags: scala, console

when using GroovyConsole I've found that i'ts much more useful then scala command-line REPL. Does anyone know will it be ScalaConsole anytime soon? It will certainly help to fiddle with Scala and learn its ways

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if there is something like GooovyConsole, but there is [Kojo](http://www.kogics.net/sf%3akojo). It's more than a console, but could used as a console.

Comment: Scalalide http://code.google.com/p/scalide/ seems like a proper Graphical REPL/Interpreter